# Entity Framework extension method (partial class)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, partial

Suppose I have following code

```
List<Common.Models.Log> logs = new MyEntities().Logs
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.Date)
            .Take(50)
            .ToList();
```

in need to create a partial class of "Logs" for call method like

```
List<Common.Models.Log> logs = new MyEntities().Logs.TakeFirst50OrderDateDesc();
```

Im trying to create the partial class for call the method from MyEntities().Logs

```
namespace Common.DataLayers
{
    public partial class Log : DbSet<Log>
    {
        public List<Log> TakeFirst50OrderDateDesc()
        {
            //blablabla
            return new List<Log>();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't see TakeFirst50OrderDateDesc after new MyEntities().Logs. Is possible im wrong to define the constructor of the partial class? How I can solve it? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for an extension method in this case?  I'm not quite sure if you can do extension methods on Generics (DbSet<Log>) but I think you can

Comment: That what you need is Repository pattern. Class Log doesn't have to contain any logic, it' s just a model for data representing.

Comment: I think you have right @Maybe, but what I need to use instead of DbSet<Log> for get my function as extension method?

Comment: I personally think repositories are nearly always the wrong answer.  Ayende (of HibernatingRhinos and RavenDB fame) agrees: http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an extension method like:

```
public static IQueryable<Log> TakeFirst50OrderDateDesc(this IQueryable<Log> top50)
{
    return top50.OrderByDescending(o => o.Date)
    .Take(50);

}
```

You can then access it exactly how you'd expect:

```
var logs = context.Logs.TakeFirst50OrderDateDesc().ToList();
```

Comment: good, now I understand for extension method i need to have a static method, and also my partial class should be static. But if i use "public static partial class Log : DbSet<Log>" I get "Static class 'Common.DataLayers.Log' cannot derive from type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Common.DataLayers.Log>'. Static classes must derive from object."

Comment: You really shouldn't need partial classes at all.  Just the extension method  I tend to have a folder named Extensions, then put my extension methods in those.  What's great here is you keep things IQueryable, so you can create almost a fluent dialect: context.Logs.TakeFirst(50).WhereLogTypeIs(LogType.Critical) then EF will do the hard stuff